# PersistenceUnit: fabricaweb2 Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Estou com esse erro abaixo, nao está conseguindo criar a EntityManager. Estou usando o maven e a pasta `META-INF` esta dentro de **src/main/resources** na pasta raiz onde ficam as entidades **src/main/java**.

Erros abaixo quando executo:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: fabricaweb2] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at fabricaweb2.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 5 more
```

Segue o persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="fabricaweb2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <!-- dados da conexao -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/fabricaweb2db"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <!-- atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

    </properties> 
</persistence-unit>
```

Segue a classe teste

```
package fabricaweb2;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import br.com.fabricaprogramador.entidades.Usuario;

public class TestHibernate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fabrica de EntityManagerFactory
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fabricaweb2");
        // Gerenciador de entidades
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // Cria o Objeto Usuario
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setNome("Pedro"); 
        usuario.setLogin("p");
        usuario.setSenha("234"); 
        // Inicando a Transação
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        // Prepara a instrução SQL 
        em.persist(usuario);
        // Confirmando a transação, fazendo a persistencia no banco 
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

Segue o pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.fabricaprogramador</groupId>
<artifactId>fabricaprogramador</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Dependdecias do Hibernate -->

<dependencies>

    <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.hibernate </groupId>
        <artifactId> hibernate-validator </artifactId>
        <version> 4.3.0.Final </version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Driver jdbc do postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>fabricaweb2</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Segue o novo erro:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
    at fabricaweb2.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o postgres está na porta 80, e não na padrão 5432 ou alguma outra? Já tentou `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fabricaweb2db` no lugar de `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/fabricaweb2db` ?

Comment: Alias, agora ta aparecendo este erro 'No Persistence provider for EntityManager named fabricaweb2db'

Comment: Removir essa linha '<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>' num sei se era essa tag q voce falo, mas o erro continua o mesmo ..

Comment: Depois de fazer umas tentativas aqui agora é o banco que deu problema. ERROR: ' Could not open connection '

Comment: Vou tentar reproduzir aqui

Comment: Okye Bruno no aguardo.. Estou suspeitando da versão do postgre, no pom.xml

Comment: Neste seu caso, apenas incluindo o dialeto explicitamente funcionou. Inclua o *stack trace* completo do *Could not open connection*

Comment: Okey Bruno irei editar a pergunta e inserir o o stack trace completo, porque aqui nao cabe :D

Comment: `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"`: este é o erro agora, então há algum problema com seu usuário/senha

Comment: vdd. Não to entendendo porque ja coloquei e senha 'root' e usuario 'root'  e esse erro tbem aparece, estou no em causo desse erro..

Comment: Depois que adicionei as depencias do slf4j e fiz algumas alteracoes no projeto, o erro está somente no senha 'root' e usuario 'root' .

Answer (score 1):

Inclua o dialeto do postgres no arquivo persistence.xml como abaixo:

`<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>`

Comment: Obrigado coloquei essa propriedade, me ajudou mas agora surgui outro erro: ' Could not open connection '

Comment: Sobre o novo erro, a senha está incorreta. Você já usou o cliente do banco Postgres (pgAdminIII) para validar as credenciais e conectar ao banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, a configuracao de postgre está no persistence.xml